# Maping URL with location on /var/www/html/app inexistent

Tags: apache2.4

I'm trying to block this URL on apache app/index.php/admin/authentication/sa/login with below text added on httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    AllowOverride none
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from Some IP from internal network
</Directory>
```

But it doesn't work and I don't understand the mapping. Actually the URL doesn't have a mapping folder, file.

```
drwxrwxr-x.   2 apache apache    40 May 26 13:22 admin
drwxrwxr-x.  15 apache apache   256 Mar  2 12:58 application
drwxrwxr-x.   7 apache apache   102 Mar  2 12:58 assets
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache 15202 Mar  2 12:58 buildVueComponents.js
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache  1340 Mar  2 12:58 composer.json
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache  3275 Mar  2 12:58 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxr-x.   5 apache apache   180 Mar  2 12:58 docs
drwxrwxr-x.  19 apache apache  4096 Mar  2 12:58 framework
drwxrwxr-x.   2 apache apache    37 Mar  2 12:58 html
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache  6615 Mar  2 12:58 index.php
drwxrwxr-x.   5 apache apache    73 Mar  2 12:58 installer
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache 49473 Mar  2 12:58 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x. 102 apache apache  4096 Mar  2 12:58 locale
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache    80 Mar  2 12:58 manifest.yml
drwxrwxr-x.   4 apache apache    31 Mar  2 12:58 modules
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache    62 Mar  2 12:58 package.json
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache  1140 Mar  2 12:58 phpci.yml
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache   468 Mar  2 12:58 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxr-x.   3 apache apache    36 Mar  2 12:58 plugins
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache  1378 Mar  2 12:58 psalm.xml
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache  2742 Mar  2 12:58 README.md
drwxrwxr-x.   9 apache apache  4096 Mar  2 12:58 tests
drwxrwxr-x.   5 apache apache    49 Mar  2 12:58 themes
drwxrwxr-x.  37 apache apache  4096 Mar  2 12:58 third_party
drwxrwxr-x.   6 apache apache   107 Jun 12 12:51 tmp
drwxrwxr-x.  10 apache apache   139 Mar  2 12:58 upload
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 apache apache   360 Mar  2 12:58 yarn.lock
```

How can I block an URL that doesn't exist as mapping on `/var/www/html/application`. I don't have any folder `index.php/admin/authentication/sa/login`. `index.php` is a file, not a directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Location tag handle the unmapped URL requests. So it works with below code but with below code it doesn't allow the IP to access the page. I'm doing something wrong?

<Location "/index.php/admin/authentication/sa/login">
AllowOverride none 
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.10.10.10
</ Location>